# What are the design guidelines to make interfaces friendly to dyslexics?

Tags: usability, accessibility, research, guidelines

I've come across [this question](http://www.quora.com/User-Interfaces/How-do-I-design-an-interface-to-be-more-accessible-to-dyslexics) on Quora where it's likely to be forgotten.

Unlike other disabilities that are often considered in design, [dyslexia has many forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslexia). As a result, the guidelines can't be just one-liner, such as "use X font" or "make sure contrast ratio is Y".

The best answer must cite hard evidence.

Comment: There's some attempted "dyslexic fonts" but that's all I'm aware of in particular

Comment: @BenBrocka: Yeah. I found a couple of questions where "dyslexic-friendly" fonts came up but nothing thorough.

Comment: "The best answer must cite research studies." You really expect someone to do all this homework for you?

Comment: @Diodeus: Just like I do homework for others.

Comment: Answers with citations are better than answers which are just opinions.

Comment: Interesting reads. I've just learned a lot from following the links above. However, in my humble opinion, I would think the main thing is to keep text as concise as possible, and to complement the text with videos and instructional illustrations, tables, diagrams and animations where appropriate. Bear in mind that otherwise excellent three point article on the Accessites website was from 2006. Web-based video has come on a lot since then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There a number of one pagers that talk about how you might design a site for users with dyslexia, I would recommend this three part series *Designing for Dyslexics* as a solid foundation:

- [Part 1](http://accessites.org/site/2006/10/designing-for-dyslexics-part-1-of-3/) (Definition of dyslexia, population size, implications/effects)
- [Part 2](http://accessites.org/site/2006/11/designing-for-dyslexics-part-2-of-3/) (Lower color contrast & visually impaired users)
- [Part 3](http://accessites.org/site/2006/11/designing-for-dyslexics-part-3-of-3/) (Typography, layouts, language style, information architecture, screen readers)

Here is a [style guide from the British Dyslexia Association](http://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/about-dyslexia/further-information/dyslexia-style-guide.html).

Comment: Wow. I'm pleasantly surprised that such rare & specialized materials were found so quickly!

Comment: "Use a plain, evenly spaced sans serif font such as Arial and Comic Sans" :-/

Comment: @RogerAttrill it's talking about readability, not good looks :) Comic Sans WAS designed for easy readability, albiet on low resolution devices.

Comment: Comic Sans just happens to be more suitable than most from the commonly available fonts, but nevertheless was not *designed* with dyslexia (or even early reading) in mind. On the other hand [specialist fonts](http://www.dyslexic.com/fonts) such as [Lexia Readable](http://www.k-type.com/?p=884), [Dyslexie](http://www.studiostudio.nl/project-dyslexie/) and [Read Regular](http://www.readregular.com/english/background.html) which tackle the specific issues may prove superior, especially when trying to be *inclusive of* dyslexic readers but not *exclusive* to them.

Comment: Better late then never: the accessites articles are detailed, and contain a lot of information. However, the author makes a large number of claims about (amongst other things) dyslexia but never references any sources.