# Dyslexia friendly colors for wider audience?

Tags: accessibility, user-research, readability, color-scheme

I have met few dyslexic people and asked them about their reading style.

Some of them said that typing on black key board with white writing is easier for them, it helps them identify the shape of the letter faster than their mac (which I checked had a white-ish keyboard).

Some of them also suggested that 'Serif' fonts are better to interpret.

It's not that they cannot understand or read but, some efforts perhaps? Something that could make their load easier :)

Is there any evidence that certain color schemes are easier for dyslexic people to read?

Comment: You might find some advice at this related question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19071/what-are-the-design-guidelines-to-make-interfaces-friendly-to-dyslexics

Comment: It's just as much about giving people choices. lmgtfy: [Usability vs Dyslexia](http://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/usability-versus-dyslexia/) and [My Web My Way](http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/guides/change_colours/)

Comment: Thanks @RogerAttrill and CJ Franken . The links are wonderful and I think, they are worth a read. Please close this question. Thanks. :)

Comment: This might help too: [Font design and typographic choices for dyslexic readers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11543/font-design-and-typographic-choices-for-dyslexic-readers/12556#12556)

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with the question, it might be interesting for you: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0075634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than colors that are valid choices when it comes to dyslexia, and the most important part is the ability for the dyslectic person to make the choice of her own:

> To combat Dyslexia:
>
> - Allow background and text colours to be user defined.
> - Do not use justified paragraph alignment.
> - Ensure adequate line-spacing (120% - 150%).
> - Keep line lengths down to 12 words on average.
> - Allow the user to select the font and it's size.

Reference: [Colour usage: Dyslexia](http://websemantics.co.uk/tutorials/accessibility_workshop/sessions/session2/05.colour_usage/05.dyslexia/)